# Spritekit Horizontal ScrollView

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift3

I'm building a gaming using spritekit.
It's an arcade-like type of game. Now, in my game I have different backgrounds/levels, and I want the player to be able to select a level. (Each level of course will be unlocked after the previous level has been finished, but I think i got that part down).

What I need to achieve is the scroll-like view when you choose the level. I have searched the web for weeks and I tried multiple ways to integrate it. I've tried using UIKit and straight through spritekit but couldn't succeed. I've deleted all my code from my different tries...

Here is an image to show exacty what I need.

I really appreciate any help, I really have no clue.[image]

Comment: Just build the entire thing in a spritekit scene.  Use a camera to pan where you want to pan to, and attach a background image to your camera with a very low zPosition to make it appear static

Comment: You cannot use UIKit objects in an SKScene, so when I made a menu like this, I used a UIViewController instead of an SKScene and added a horizontal UIScrollView for the level selection menu

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog can you post your code please?

Comment: I have no direction

Comment: @YannaiHarel the code MSU Bulldog made would be pages long, and custom to his project's needs. It won't be simple. It should be, but it's not. You are better off following KnightOfDragon's thinking, and doing this in SpriteKit with a moving camera, or passing objects underneath a camera.

Comment: Actually the code was just in one UIViewController (1 page long) so it was pretty simple, but I'm not going to post my code for you to copy/paste... If you try it and run into an issue then I will be happy to help you solve any problems

Comment: @Confused I tried using a camera, but I don't have the same smoothness as a normal uiscrollview, I feel like it's not dynamic enough.

Comment: @MSU_Bulldog can you at least give me a direction, I've never used uiscrollview and never succeeded integrating it with spritekit.

Answer (score 0):

So I managed to do this by creating an skspritenode with every menu child node inside it, and then when touches moved I update the sprite node position.x